# How to put sound in an android animation?

Tags: android, animation, audio, imageview

I need to make an animation with sound. IE when an ImageView is rotating it makes a sound like  tic tic tic until it ends

Comment: play sound using mediaplayer when you start rotating the imageview.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For little sounds like a tick or tock, use SoundPool. It's much more efficient to use soundpool, rather than a complicated and heavy MediaPlayer!

[Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/getting-your-feet-wet-in-androids-soundpool/877)'s a decent tutorial on SoundPool.

Also use AnimationListeners to synchronize your animation and audio.

Comment: @Kisama329: Thanks for accepting, you may also want to upvote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start playing the music immediately after the animation starts . Use AnimationListener for the animation. In onAnimationEnd() , stop the music playing.